# jquery on slide remove hover state of the button

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

Using Jquery, I have a simple slide down of a div when you click a button.
**The problem is, the button :hover state is not removed.**

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6gHb/9/

(Small note, on the version of my site, I actually need to mouseover the button again, then mouseout, for it to go back to normal state).

Here is the JS code:

```
   $("a").click(function() {
        var div = $("#toggleDiv"); 
        if (!div.hasClass("open")) {
            div.animate({
                height: "300px"
            },"fast").addClass("open");
        } else {
            div.animate({
                height: "150px"
            },"fast").removeClass("open");

        }
        return false;
    });
```

As you'll see in the fiddle, the a link stays red after the slide. Which doesn't look like a big problem in this simple example, but on my site, it's really annoying.

My question is:

**Am I doing something wrong? Or How can I remove the :hover state on click?**

(I have a similar problem with Twitter bootstrap tooltip).

Comment: To clarify, I'm making more or less the exact same "Show more" button that you have on Youtube in the video description.

Answer (score 1):

In my tests it removed itself whenever I moved my mouse but it's still unpleasant to keep the link "hovered". You can trick it like this:

```
$(this).unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');
```

However, if you have binded events for those events, you should reattach once you remove them.

This ***only*** applies if you have something like this:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
//Do fancy stuff
});
```

So you would do something like this:

```
    function hoverLinkEffect(e) {
        // Do fancy stuff                                
    }

//Then on the a click event handler
$(this).unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout').on('hover',hoverLinkEffect);
```

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(this).unbind('onmouseover').unbind('onmouseout');
        var div = $("#toggleDiv"); 
        if (!div.hasClass("open")) {
            div.animate({
                height: "300px"
            },"fast").addClass("open");
        } else {
            div.animate({
                height: "150px"
            },"fast").removeClass("open");

        }
        return false;
    });

});​
```

Comment: Thanks. But I seem to still have the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Y6gHb/10/ and how would I rebind the event? I need to create another listener?

Comment: In which browser are you trying it?

Comment: Chrome latest version on Mac.

Comment: Updated the answer with rebinding. I have tested in Firefox, Chrome and even on Explorer and once I click, the link becomes blue in your example.